# Java for loop to get the sum of numbers

Tags: java, for-loop

I am writing a program that asks the user to input a positive integer and to calculate the sum from 1 to that number. Need some tips on what i'm doing wrong.

Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a positive integer");
    int getNumber=keyboard.nextInt();
    int x;
    int total = 0;
    for (x=1;x<=getNumber;x++) {
        total=x+1;
    }
    System.out.println(total);
}
```

Comment: do `total=total+x` instead of `total=x+1`,  that will do.

Comment: you can debug and find out the problem.

Comment: What is the approach to debug?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems can help. Also, see this excellent article on debugging techniques by Eric Lipert: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a positive integer");
        int getNumber = keyboard.nextInt();
        int x;
        int total = 0;
        for (x=1;x <= getNumber;x++) {
            total += x;
        }
        System.out.println(total);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic should be changed from

```
total=x+1;  // you evaluate total each iteration to initialize it with x+1
```

to

```
total=total+x; // you keep adding to the existing value of total in each iteration
```

Answer (score 0):

to get the sum from 1 to the input number you want to increment `total` by each time with the new number `x`.

so do `total = total + x`.

also a tip:

you want to declare `int x` with your for loop. delete `int x` and do the following:

```
for (int x=1; x<=getNumber; x++) {
    total = total + x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is:

your total value is wrong, Because of this line:

```
total=x+1;
```

It should be:

```
total = total + x;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
total=x+1;
```

to this:

```
total=total+x;
```